# Excel: How to Transpose a column of data into a row using a formula and not using copy and paste transpose

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

Within the screenshot, I would like to Transpose a column of data (Column A) into a row (Row 7) using a formula, cell referencing and not using copy and paste transpose. Would someone be able to help?

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 2):

Use the formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(A1:A3)
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need to use CSE for this. `=TRANSPOSE(A1:A3)` is enough.

Comment: @FlexYourData Thanks. I have edited the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the formula below:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$6,COLUMN(A1))
```

[image]